# How do I redirect to another page from RadPane in ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik, rad-controls

I put a RadSplitter onto a page (parent.aspx) that has two vertical panes. On the left side there is a navigation menu. If you click on an item of the menu, it will open the .aspx pages on the right side next to the navigation menu. Now I want to redirect the web application from pages that open in the right side pane (I want to redirect to a complete new webform, for example Default.aspx).

I want to redirect to another page, but when I redirect the page, Default.aspx opens in contentPane (right side). I want to open this page in a new page.

Comment: your code please? What have you done so far ?

Comment: I put a page that contain a radsplitter that have 2 pane. left and right

Comment: When  click a link in left pane, a page open in right pane. (For example: when click in child link, child.aspx open in right pane)

Comment: Child.aspx have a link to other page. (For example: child.aspx have Default link that must open Default.aspx)

Comment: Now , When I click to default link, Default.aspx open in same page.It is mean, Default.aspx open in right pane

Comment: But I want to open Default.aspx in new page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call this JavaScript in the content page pane:

```
window.top.location = "the-page-i-want-to-go-to.aspx"
```

This can be attached to a button click, or whatever other client-side event you use. What is important is to access the iframe hierarchy and navigate the topmost one.

If you are using anchor tags this is even easier, just add target="_top" to them.